# Review board delete a review

Tags: git, review-board

I am using review board post-review and git. Currently i have created a review which has too many changes. Now i want to delete the review and create a new request with limited changes. Is is possible to delete it?

Note: I tried discard the changes and tried submitted the limited changes. But it got appended to the same review.

Comment: I have added an answer, but it seems staight-forward, please add more technical info if the problem is more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

The review board administrator can delete a review request, no regular user can do this.

You can create any review request according to the type of the review request, if it is post-commit or pre-commit review.

For pre-commit, You can specify the changes then upload them to the review board.

For post commit, You can just choose a commit from your source code control tool to create a review request.